# Fly the Blackjack

Tags: final-fantasy-6

Can you fly the *Blackjack* freely in the overworld in *Final Fantasy VI*?

I just finished the opera scene and it brought me to the other continent. I can't seem to be able to fly it freely like the *Highwind* in *Final Fantasy VII*.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can freely fly the *Blackjack* once you progress far enough into the story.  I believe after you complete raiding the Imperial Magitek facility, you can start flying the airship to wherever you want.

Comment: The party split-up event must be finished first as I recall.